# Last Inserted Auto Increment Id using ASP.NET MVC & Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Here I'm going to get last inserted auto-increment `ID` for the `Newstbl`. But here in the normal scenario we can take it as order by DESCENDING ORDER & get the first record.

But here I use ASP.NET MVC & Entity Framework, I'm stuck there. `NewsId` is the auto-increment Id

My code:

```
public int GetLastInsertedId()
{
        return (from x in context.Newstbl
                orderby x.NewsId 'DESC' 
                select x)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get this way using Linq Method Query syntax:

```
public int GetLastInsertedId()
{
   return context.Newstbl.OrderByDescending(x=>x.NewsId).First().NewsId;

}
```

and using query expression syntax:

```
public int GetLastInsertedId()
{
  return (from x in context.Newstbl 
          select x).OrderByDescending(x=>x.NewsId).First().NewsId;
}
```

Comment: If you need only Id The best way `context.Newstbl.OrderByDescending(x=>x.NewsId).Select(x=>x.NewsId).First()` Executing `ToList()` force EF to fetch all rows. And using of Select fetch only id.

Comment: you are rugh @py3r3str agreed

Answer (score 6):

IF you've properly set up your EF mapping, then basically when you insert a new `NewsTbl` object, the auto-incremented `ID` should be available as soon as you've called `.SaveChanges()` on your context.

So if you do this:

```
using(YourEFContext ctx = new YourEFContext())
{
    NewsTbl news = new NewsTbl();

    // set some properties here on "news".....

    ctx.NewsTbl.Add(news);

    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

then after the call to `.SaveChanges()`, your `news` object should actually already contain the auto-incremented `ID` property.... so I don't really understand why you're going through all this trouble of trying to read out the last inserted auto-increment `ID` - it's already there for you, in your object.

Comment: Agreed - this is one of the features I love about EF!